# client can't connect to Perforce server

Tags: networking, amazon-web-services, perforce

The error:

```
p4v can't connect to host server
Operation cancelled by user.
Connect to server failed; check $P4PORT.
TCP connect to ec2-3-96-163-100.ca-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com:1666 failed.
connect: 3.96.163.100:1666: WSAETIMEDOUT, A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. 
 
host: aws ec2  
host side environment variables inside ~/.bashrc :  
P4PORT=tcp46:ip-172-31-14-9.ca-central-1.compute.internal:1666  
P4ROOT=/home/ec2-user/p4root  

client: windows 11  
system environment variables :  
variable name: P4PORT  
value: tcp46:ip-172-31-14-9.ca-central-1.compute.internal:1666
```

command I typed to start p4d:

```
p4d -J /home/ec2-user/p4logs/p4journal -L /home/ec2-user/p4logs/p4err -p tcp46:ip-172-31-14-9.ca-central-1.compute.internal:1666 -r /home/ec2-user/p4root &
```

p4d is shown to be running when I ran top on aws to check.
running

```
ss  -ltnp | grep p4d
```

it showed:

```
LISTEN 0      128      172.31.14.9:1666      0.0.0.0:*    users:(("p4d",pid=32457,fd=3))
```

1666 is the port number

links I looked at to setup p4port p4d
[Communicating port information](https://www.perforce.com/manuals/p4sag/Content/P4SAG/installing-linux-non-package-port.html)
[Telling Helix Server applications which port to connect to](https://www.perforce.com/manuals/p4sag/Content/P4SAG/installing-linux-non-package-port.html)
[starting the helix server](https://www.perforce.com/manuals/p4sag/Content/P4SAG/install.unix.start.html)

using ss and netstat:
[netstat](https://www.tecmint.com/find-out-which-process-listening-on-a-particular-port/)
[ss](https://www.tecmint.com/ss-command-examples-in-linux/)

Comment: You’re running in AWS. Did you set its firewall to allow the connection?

Comment: Thank you! Should I set it on the AWS server or on my own computer?